# Training with an input size of 1 causes NaN in subsequent predictions

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, mnist, tensorflow.js

I'm following the MNIST tutorial [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html#0) for recognizing handwritten characters.

I'm able to load and recognize handwritten digits without issue, but now I want to train the model again on new images (specifically one at a time).

For some reason, when I choose a training size equal to 1, all my predictions become NaN.

If I pick a value >=2, it works fine.

Train Function:

```
async function train(model, data)
{
    const TRAIN_DATA_SIZE = 1; // WHEN THIS IS 1, CAUSES PREDICT TO OUTPUT NaN

    const [trainXs, trainYs] = tf.tidy(() =>
    {
        const d = data.nextTrainBatch(TRAIN_DATA_SIZE);
        return [
            d.xs.reshape([TRAIN_DATA_SIZE, 28, 28, 1]),
            d.labels
        ];
    });

    console.log(trainXs.dataSync());
    console.log(trainYs.dataSync());

    return model.fit(trainXs, trainYs);
}
```

The code for `nextTrainBatch` is [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/mnist_data.js).

Example output for prediction:

```
currentTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [1, PIXELSSQUARED]);

const output = model.predict(currentTensor.reshape([1, 28, 28, 1]));
const prediction_value = Array.from(output.argMax(1).dataSync());
console.log(output.dataSync());
```

When training size is 2 or greater:

```
Float32Array(10) [3.308702423154841e-9, 5.89648436744028e-8, 0.00005333929220796563, 0.8063259720802307, 7.401082784824764e-13, 1.1464327087651327e-7, 6.5924318955190575e-12, 0.1936144232749939, 0.000004253268798493082, 0.000001676815713835822]
```

When training size is 1:

```
Float32Array(10) [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Comment: The model is reaching a numerical instability. Use an optimizer such as SGD might help. However, using a batch size of 1 is practically not a good idea as the model might oscillate around optimum values

Comment: Is there a better way of incorporating user / further feedback into my model after it has been trained?

Comment: What do you mean by "incorporating user" ?

Comment: What I mean is - I want the user to select the correct value after the model has made it's prediction e.g. Make Prediction, Select Correct Output, Retrain based on this information

Comment: if you want to train further, you would need to have the data that matches the model inputShape. So the value predicted and the result chosen by the user will be collected and It can be used to train the model further.

Comment: My input does match the input shape but a sample size of 1 is causing the issue...

Comment: There is no point in training with only one sample size. Gather many values from the user before training

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear... I already have a trained model on X amount of images -see here -> https://run.ancientbrain.com/run.php?world=4396075130

I'd like to let the user to click the correct output after the prediction to improve the model(s)...

I have it somewhat working in that example but it's a hack, I need to load one image from the training set, bundle it with my user input (the drawing) and then call refit...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204472/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-tomselleck).

Answer (score 0):

The model is reaching a numerical instability. Use an optimizer such as SGD might help. However, using a batch size of 1 is practically not a good idea as the model might oscillate around optimum values

> I want the user to select the correct value after the model has made it's prediction e.g. Make Prediction, Select Correct Output, Retrain based on this information

if you want to train further, you would need to have the data that matches the model inputShape. So the value predicted and the result chosen by the user will be collected and It can be used to train the model further

```
// the model has been trained
y = model.predict(x) // predict
```

Suppose that the user will validate the result y. To train further

```
model.fit(x, y)
```

And the cycle continue